# The Web Server Could Not Find the Requested Resource

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, iis-7, windows-vista

I have a .NET 3.5 Web application on VS 2008 SP1 running on Vista Ultimate 32 SP1. I created an Application under the Default Web Site. So the url to the app is "http://localhost/mysite". The application folder is pointing to the solution folder and it is outside the iisroot folder. Anonymous and Integrated Auth (Windows) is enabled in IIS7 for this web application "mysite".

I gave full permissions to "Network Service" user to the application folder (which is outside of iisroot).

When I hit F5 to star debugging, I get the "Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server could not find the requested resource." error.

---

I fired up TcpView (Sysinternals) to see what app is actually running and keeping an handle on that port and I found out there is no app listening on that port. This is really weird... Any creative ideas?

---

I can hit the URL "http://localhost/mysite" without a problem. That web application is set up to be the start up project and Default.aspx is the start up page.

There is an .asmx service in the prject as well. The Default.aspx is making use of that asmx service. The AutoCompleteExtender (From the AJAX Control Toolkit) is using this asmx service.

Everything works by the way. The issue is the debugging... I suspect the asmx service is causing this but i don't know. This is driving me nuts...

Comment: @Pradeep: I am running Visual Studio as Admin. In fact, it would not run a web application under IIS of you are not running VS in admin user. And yes debug=true in the web.config file.

Answer (score 36):

For those encountering this with **Visual-Studio 2012 or 2013** and/or **Windows 8 or 10** do the following.

You have to add .Net 3.5 (or 4.5) to your **Turn Windows Features on or off** window.  You get to it via:

> Control Panel -> Programs -> Turn Windows Features on or off

[image]

Click the `Asp.Net 3.5` and the  `Asp.Net 4.5` check box in the `IIS > WWW Service > Application Development Features` folder.

Comment: Mine were disabled! Would've been searching for ages if not for this, thanks! +1

Answer (score 16):

open IIS7 (run > inetmgr) and go to the Feature view. Open the ISAPI and CGI Restrictions section and check if your .Net version has the correct restriction (for example, if you're working with 4.0 is should be on "Allowed")

Comment: In visual studio 13, this work for me..
Close all solutions in Visual Studio
open IIS7 (run > inetmgr)
Click your top node (computer name)
Open the "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions" option
check if your .Net version has the correct restriction (for example, if you're working with 4.0 is should be on "Allowed")

Answer (score 8):

One more common problem is that site or application path is not started.

Comment: Aaaaargh! +1 ... Why doesn't it just say this!?

Answer (score 7):

I had same problem and solved it. You can try  following: navigate to the root folder of your web application and find file that has ".csproj.user" extension ad delete it. Close all instances of Visual Studio and start again.
Then hit F5.
Otherwise hit CTRL+ALT+P and attach to w3wc.exe process.
Hope it helps.

Comment: CTRL-ALT-P Worked a charm. in windows 2008 r2, vs2010
deleting the .user file did nothing.

Comment: Deleting .csproj.user file worked for me too (no restart was required in my case, VS2013 update 4). Just to clarify why this works: I had previously selected IIS Express for my project, and then switched to IIS. The .user file had debugging settings specific for my previous selection.

Answer (score 6):

Just managed to fix this on my dev machine: I've got UrlScan installed and had to add DEBUG to the list of AllowVerbs. Hopefully this might give you something else to go on?

Answer (score 2):

Installing Urlscan and changing the urlscan.ini with these changes solved the problem.

In ALLOWEXTENSIONS Section add .aspx and in ALLOWVERBS Section add DEBUG.

Don't forget to restart IIS.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with XP sp3 and I have been struggling for days. Adding .aspx and DEBUB to urlscan.ini solved the problem.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to fix Web Service Extentions

Adminitrative Tools -> Manage my server -> IIS - > Web Service Extensions

ASP.NET 2.0 was prohibited somehow, fixed that and it started working.

Cheers!

Comment: lol, I faced that issue again and I tried everything but no luck. Came back to my own answer searching for it. Thanks SO, you are my second brain. :)

Comment: This was exactly my problem.  By default the ASP 4.0 installed with this set to prohibited.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to re-register ASP.NET for IIS.
You can do it by running the following command from command prompt

```
systemroot\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ versionNumber \aspnet_regiis -i
```

*for example:* `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -i`

Answer (score 2):

for me, the default website in IIS was stopped, after starting it, I managed to get it working

Comment: Yes. Make sure IIS itself is running, and the appropriate app pool is running too.

Answer (score 1):

That should not be an issue - what do you have as your startup page?  Also, in the 'Start Options' for the web (under properties page), make sure that you have 'Start URL' selected and put in the Url you mentioned above.

The error you are having should not be permission specific, so i would look elsewhere - also check if you can hit the url successfully before debugging (manual put the url in your browser) "http://localhost/mysite".

Answer (score 1):

I am using Windows 7 32-bit with VS2005 and IIS 7.5. My web.config had debug="true" by default. I set up IIS physical path to point to the development folder, and followed the above tips. I am not using UrlScan. I am running VS2005 as an admin. I still could not get it working.

What got it working was adding the IIS_IUSRS account w/full access to the development website root folder, and using CTRL+ALT+P (Attach to process) to attach to w3wp.exe.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this issue is pretty simple.  If the Web Site is pointing to a different location and if the Virtual Directory is pointing to a different directory, you will receive this error.

I suggest that you point the Web Site to the same directory as the Virtual Directory and the issue will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this same problem and none of the suggestions worked.

My problem was that my project URL was set to `http://localhost/service`. Changing this to my IP address worked.

Comment: worked, but I needed to change my host file to use my IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I was using Default Web site on IIS also, but weren't able to launch it by debuging or just by simple browse.

It turned out Default site was stopped!! Started it, and all good.

Answer (score 1):

For me, someone had updated the web.config for Request Filtering, in particular they only allowed GET and POST verbs. To use local IIS you need to allow the DEBUG verb too.

```
<verbs allowUnlisted="false">
     <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
     <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
     <add verb="DEBUG" allowed="true"/>
</verbs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

- Turn of UAT
- Add the user the website is running under (and/or yourself) to the Debuggers or Administrators group (temporarily)
- Turn on IIS logging

Comment: What do you mean by UAT? Do you mean UAC? If so, it has nothing to do with this issue. IIS logging is on by default.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, have you set up Debug=true in your web.config. Generally when you are using VS's inbuilt web server, then it is able to detect that you are trying to debug but debug flag is off and it warns you. But in your case you have setup IIS and VS might not be able to do this check.

Another point is you are running on Vista. In vista even if you are the admin of system, Vista does not treat you as Admin. Your security tokens are created as of normal user. In order to do the debugging IIS hosted website (note: when using inbuilt web server, VS 2008 manages the debugging), run the VS 2008 as administrator. That could solve the issue.

Comment: I am running Visual Studio as Admin. In fact, it would not run a web application under IIS of you are not running VS in admin user. And yes debug=true in the web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem, but am able to debug if I go via the Tools -> Attach to Process menu then select the aspnet_wp process.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your web project's properties, then the "web" tab, then make sure that you're using the Visual Studio Development Server and not Local IIS or the custom webserver. I'm on VS2010 with Win7 and another developer was developing using a custom webserver URL and not the VS Dev Server

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the Project Url in the Web tab of the project properties doesn't contain invalid characters. In my case it had a "+" character, which caused this error to appear.

Answer (score 0):

This section in my web.config caused the error:

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
            <add segment="......" />
            <add segment="....." />
            ........
        </hiddenSegments>
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Carefully rewiew it - maybe your debugging file is restricted for direct view in browser there.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything to no avail, but once I got the csproj.user out of there, low and behold, the site loaded.  Don't worry about deleting it, as soon as the site load, it will create a new one.